# coerce list with uneven matrices into tibble

Tags: r, list, tibble

I have a list like so:

```
lst <-
list(structure(c("1", "[19]"), .Dim = 1:2), structure("1", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L)), structure(c("1", "[41]"), .Dim = 1:2), structure(c("1", 
"[55]"), .Dim = 1:2), structure(c("1", "[56]"), .Dim = 1:2), 
    structure(c("1", "[84]"), .Dim = 1:2))
```

How do I convert this into a `tibble` so that:

```
rslt <-
tibble(batch=c(1,1,1,1,1,1), id=c("[19]","","[41]","[55]","[56]","[84]"))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  batch    id
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1  [19]
2     1      
3     1  [41]
4     1  [55]
5     1  [56]
6     1  [84]
```

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse);lst %>% map_df(~as.data.frame(.))`

Comment: It works, but I got the following warning messages: `1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector...`

Comment: I forgot to add the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` i.e. `lst %>% map_df(~as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`

Comment: Can you explain how it works?

Comment: I posted a solution below with the explanation

Comment: FYI, the list you have here is not nested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We loop through the `lst` and convert it to `data.frame` as it is a `matrix`.  Normally, using `do.call(rbind, lst)` should work if the dimensions were the same.  But, here it is not the same.  Using the `map_dfr` from `purrr`, we loop through each `lst` element, apply the function `as.data.frame` to convert it to `data.frame` and at the same time, we get a single dataset as we are using `map_dfr`

> map_dfr() and map_dfc() return data frames created by row-binding and
>   column-binding respectively. They require dplyr to be installed.

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(lst, ~as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Note: It returns NA for elements not present and it is better than having blank elements

Comment: @Sotos I think it is slightly different as it is a `list` of `vector`s

Comment: what does the squiggle `~` in `~as.data.frame` do?

Comment: Instead of using the pipe `%>%`, why can't I simply replace the `(.)` with `lst` like so? `map_df(~as.data.frame(lst))`

Comment: @Sati It won't work, because `map_df` needs a `.f` and `.x` which is the function and the object.  i.e `map_dfr(.x, .f, ..., .id = NULL)`  With only `map_df(~as.data.frame(lst))` there is only .`.f`

Answer (score 3):

There is also a very convenient function in `plyr` package that can easily handle that,

```
plyr::rbind.fill(lapply(lst, as.data.frame))

#  V1   V2
#1  1 [19]
#2  1 <NA>
#3  1 [41]
#4  1 [55]
#5  1 [56]
#6  1 [84]
```